# SQL Server Concatenate To New Column With SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Please consider the following sample data:

```
Part Loc Qty
A A-1 10
A A-5 15
A B-4 7
B B-5 10
B B-6 15
```

I can query easily enough to get the location qty for each part:

```
select
    pt.Part
    ,lc.Loc
    ,lc.LocQty Qty
from
    Part pt
left join
    Loc lc
on
    pt.Part = lc.Part
```

I can also sum the locations like so:

```
select
    pt.Part
    ,sum(lc.LocQty) TotalQty
from
    Part pt
left join
    Loc lc
on
    pt.Part = lc.Part
group by
    pt.Part
```

What I want to do now is instead concatenate into a new column, each location that the part appears, like so:

```
Part TotalQty InLocations
A 32 A-1, A-5, B-4
B 25 B-5, B-6
```

What would be the best approach to this?

Many thanks

Comment: Search for something like `GROUP_CONCAT sql server`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger The tag specifically says SQL Server 2008. `STRING_AGG` didn't exist in the old days before SQL Server 2017

Comment: @Martin, yes, that's why OP should put that in to a search engine, it'll spit out alternatives

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: @HoneyBadger Fair enough, but the top results reference `STRING_AGG`, which I think is confusing if you aren't aware that this is not available in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: The GROUP-CONCAT available in MySQL is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: This is on 2012 SP3, not 2008

Comment: @AKay Did you take a look at the duplicate I linked?  The accepted answer has the exact method for achieving this pre-SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Thanks @Martin I just saw this and will try it out

Answer (score 1):

SQL SERVER replacement of `GROUP_CONCAT()` is `STRING_AGG()`.But `STRING_AGG()` was introduced in SQL Server 2017 version, you have to use combination of `STUFF` and `For XML PATH` to get your result.

```
SELECT P.PART,SUM(QTY) AS TOTALQTY,
       INLOCATIONS = STUFF(
                     (
                      SELECT ', ' + PA.LOC 
                      FROM PART AS PA 
                      WHERE PA.PART = P.PART
                      FOR XML PATH('')
                     ), 1, 2, N''
                     ) 
 FROM PART P
 GROUP BY P.PART
```

[**Check Demo here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=3ae345548f5d06d9e472c25708400b4b)